# C#, MVC - Trying to delete site cache from console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am caching parts of my site using HttpRuntime.Cache. In a different process (console) I am trying to delete some cache keys by calling the delete cache function that sits in my site. The problem is there doesn't seem to be a connection between the console cache and the site cache, because the site cache doesn't seem to be deleted. I am probably doing it wrong. Help please?

Answer (score 4):

They're running in different processes, and `HttpRuntime` is contained within the running process/context.  So your console app is clearing `Cache`, but it's the cache of your console's process, not the web application's process (which has a separate `HttpRuntime`).

If you want your console app to clear the cache of the web application, you need to expose a action method on your web application that the console application can call.  Within that action method, then you can clear the `HttpRuntime.Cache`.

*Some pseudo-code as to what your controller's action method may look like:*

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult ClearCache(){
  HttpRuntime.Cache.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I am calling the function that sits on my web app (my console proccess is reading the dll's of the site's App). But it doesn't working, neither writing to cache from there.

Comment: Reading the DLL's of another project doesn't connect you to that project's process.  You need to make a remote call into your web site via an action method or service call in order to have the web site clear its cache.  Your console app can't really clear the cache -- you need to issue a command to the web app to clear the cache.

Comment: ok I think I'm starting to understand. Can you help me with a code example of the call from the proccess?